# R subsetting from list based on comparison to data frame

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

I have a list that contains a series of loaded files. I wish to subset this list to obtain the results from each files that match values in another data frame.

For example with the following test code:

```
data.coords1 <- c(1,6,7,9,18)
data.lett1 <- c("T","T","G","C","T")

data1 <- cbind(data.coords1, data.lett1)

data.coords2 <- c(2,4,19,20)
data.lett2 <- c("G","T","G","C")

data2 <- cbind(data.coords2, data.lett2)

data.coords3 <- c(10,11,12,13,15,17)
data.lett3 <- c("C","T","C","C","T","G")

data3 <- cbind(data.coords3, data.lett3)

data.list <- list(data1, data2, data3)

ref.coords <- c(1:20)
ref.mark <- letters[1:20]
ref.MARK <- LETTERS[1:20]

ref <- cbind(ref.coords, ref.mark, ref.MARK)
```

I can obtain what I want (for one list element) with :

```
desired.data <- merge(data2,ref, by.x="data.coords1",
                       by.y="ref.coords", sort=F)
```

But how may I do this easily for the whole list?

Comment: Something like `lapply(1:length(data.list), function(i) merge(data.list[[i]],ref, by.x=paste0("data.coords",i), by.y="ref.coords", sort=F))` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(1:length(data.list), function(i) merge(data.list[[i]],ref, by.x=paste0("data.coords",i), by.y="ref.coords", sort=F))
[[1]]
  data.coords1 data.lett1 ref.mark ref.MARK
1            1          T        a        A
2            6          T        f        F
3            7          G        g        G
4            9          C        i        I
5           18          T        r        R

[[2]]
  data.coords2 data.lett2 ref.mark ref.MARK
1            2          G        b        B
2            4          T        d        D
3           19          G        s        S
4           20          C        t        T

[[3]]
  data.coords3 data.lett3 ref.mark ref.MARK
1           10          C        j        J
2           11          T        k        K
3           12          C        l        L
4           13          C        m        M
5           15          T        o        O
6           17          G        q        Q
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for the example code but I am having problems getting it to work with my real data. I'm getting the error `Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column` that I'm investigating.

Comment: No problem. So, in your real data, you don't have variables like `data.coords1`, `data.coords2`, `data.coords3`, and so on  or is it that `by.y` is not the same for all datasets in a list ?

Comment: Yes that was it, In my real data the columns in each list element are the same. It took me a while to notice what was wrong, must be tired. Thanks